# Error con socket.io y CORS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, socket, cors

estoy realizando una app con React, nodejs, express y socket, mi objetivo es hacer un chat, pero me encuentro con los siguientes errores.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:3900/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NLhNLO9'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>
> GET http://localhost:3900/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NLhNLO9
> net::ERR_FAILED

a continuación le adjunto el código:

**app.js**

```
'use strict'


// 1-  Cargar modulos de node para crear servidor
var express= require('express'); //el que crea el servidor.
var bodyParser= require('body-parser')  //recibir las peticiones
var socketio=require('socket.io');
const http= require('http'); 

var app= express();
                    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))//cargar el bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //convertir cualquier peticion que me llege a json.


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict'


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var socketio=require('socket.io');
const http= require('http');
const cors = require('cors');



var app=require('./app');

const server= http.createServer(app);
const io=socketio(server);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('We have a new connection!!!');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("User had left");
    })
    
});



//variables de entorno locales
require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('La conexion a la BD se ha realizado con exito');

           
        });

    

//LEER LOCAL HOST DE VARIABLE Y PUERTOS

const host= process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const port= process.env.PORT || 3900 ;


app.listen(port, host, ()=> {
    console.log('servidor corriendo en http://localhost:'+port + " " + host);

});
```

y en la parte del front, en el apartado del chat tengo el siguiente codigo
**chat.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';

import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket;

const Chat=({location}) =>{

       const [name, setName] = useState('');
       const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
        const ENDPOINT='localhost:3900'

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name, room}=queryString.parse(location.search);
        socket=io(ENDPOINT);

        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);
        
        console.log(socket);
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

        return (
            <div>
               <h1>Chat</h1>

            </div>

        );
   
}

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto valía más como comentario. Nunca he trabajado con express o siquiera nodejs, pero basándome en:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

creo que deberías cambiar:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

por

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
```

Comment: gracias! ya he solucionado ese error ahora me muestra el siguiente: GET http://localhost:3900/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NLm6y3N net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Ok, pero ese es un error distinto al que consultaste en tu pregunta, el cual, por lo que deduzco de tu comentario, ya fue resuelto. Como te comentaba en la respuesta, nunca he trabajado con node o express, así que desconozco su funcionamiento más de lo que una googleada me puede mostrar. Te sugiero que crees una nueva pregunta, donde compartas los detalles de este nuevo error, para que tenga más visibilidad tu nuevo problema de lo que tendría aquí en un comentario. Y recuerda que si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada. Saludos